# Angular Template does not call the <script>. Anyway around?

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-scope, mean-stack

I want to call different script based on different template. It will be heavy to load all of the script in the index page. However, Angular Template does not execute  tag.

How should I go about loading the script src?

Thanks
Here is the code for the template. All the script tags does not execute

```
 <form id= "saveAssessmentForm", method = "post">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click= "submitAssessmentData()" >    Submit</button>
     <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click= "tryAgain()" >Again</button>
   </form>
   <div id= "assessmentArea"> </div>
   <script src="../js/saveAssessment.js"></script>
   <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r61/three.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
```

In the js/saveAssessment.js

```
   console.log ("In the saveAssessment.js");
```

The string does not get printed.

Comment: Could you provide example of script code you call?

Comment: I edited my question. Please give me some enlightenments.

Comment: create a controller used in your template, this controller will get the content from the server and insert it using $sce service as trusted JS. this is an idea that might work.

Comment: Hm, so does tryAgain function not in the controller?

Comment: Do you have error in console? If there are errors, JS stop running.

Comment: i don't know what do you mean by tryAgain  function

Comment: its a single page app. all code is loaded up front.